# Understanding (and finding root of) long delay in waterfall before transactions start

Tags: performance, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights

I am trying to profile/improve our applications.  One of the things I'm having trouble explaining/understanding/finding the root cause of is some results in the End-to-end transaction details with application insights.

I get there this way:
Within Azure -> Application Insights service -> Performance tab on left.  You'll see something similar to this (I'm going to select the top one, and then click "135 Samples").  This particular method is an anonymous endpoint in a class that extends `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`.  There are 10 DI injected services in this controller.  This is a .net6 application running in East US, using a SQL Server also hosted in East US.  I'm happy to share any additional details.

[image]

The next page shows all of the requests which you can access a waterfall view of, here is an example:

[image]

My goal is to figure out *why* some of the requests have this long wait before other processes start.  In the screenshot, it looks like there is about 8s that pass before anything starts happening.  Also in the screenshot, on the left, you can see that the next request only took 574ms.  That requests waterfall is here:

[image]

After reviewing *hundreds* of these, everything is relatively consistent except that chunk of time before the first database call.  I'm looking for guidance on how I can find the cause of this.  I do have profiling enabled on this app service.

Comment: Can be anything in theory - from GC Gen 2 collection to something parallel running and consuming all resources. Or maybe transaction is doing something which is not reflected in Application Insights. Opening profile in PerfView might give some pointers.